# Why java's Math.round and Math.floor have different signature?

Tags: java, syntax

java's Math.round is following signature:

```
public static long round(double a)
```

returns long, which is quite normal, but
Math.floor signature is:

```
public static double floor(double a)
```

which returns a double, shouldn't it also return
long? which is quite weird.